# How to find application working directory?

Tags: java, android, directory

I'm new in android developing.
supped that I want to access directory which other application use it.
For example Viber app create directory which named Viber in storage.
for every phone this directory has specific address.
I want to know is there any way to know exact path of this directory?
now Im using below code to find it :

```
String  path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/viber/";
```

but its possible in other phone this directory created in other path.
anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

> supped that I want to access directory which other application use it.

An application can create zero, one, or many directories, on [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> I want to know is there any way to know exact path of this directory?

Get a job with Viber and look at their code.

> but its possible in other phone this directory created in other path

Correct. The developers of Viber are welcome to do what they wish, and there is no way for you to know where they elect to create directories. *Perhaps* they use the approach you took on all devices, though if they eventually hire somebody with some Android development talent, they will use other locations rather than clutter up the root of the user's external storage this way. Regardless, it is up to Viber's developers, and so the only way you will know what Viber does across all devices is to ask Viber.